# C++ Assert Message

Tags: c++, assert

Im really quickly trying to figure out what the "custom message" of an assert does. I can't seem to find the answer.

ie:

```
int x = -1; 
assert (x > 0 && "Number must be above 0");
```

Where does the message actually output? Because it sure isn't being displayed when I try it.

Comment: It's only useful as long as the compiler shows you the exact condition of the assert, in which case you see the string right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `assert` typically is implemented something like this (probably a whole lot more complex, but simplified here)

```
#define assert(x) if (!(x)) { assert_fail(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

void assert_fail(const char *str, const char *file, int line)
{
  std::cerr << "Assertion failed " << str << " " << file << ":" << line << std::endl;
  abort();
}
```

then adding `&& "Some string"` to the condition will make assert print the message as well. Which is quite handy for identifying WHY it went wrong. I use this exact pattern in my code.

Of course, some `assert` implementations don't print the condition that failed, in which case you won't see the string. You could fix this by replacing the existing `assert` with `my_assert` and using something like the above.

It also comes in handy if you are running your code in a debugger (e.g. in an IDE) where the string will be shown together with the condition when the debugger stops due to an assert (it may well stop somewhere deeper inside the code, but if you step back up the call-stack, it will eventually get to the point where the assert is, and you can see what the message is).

Comment: Have you yet compared the performance of your code to that of <cassert>, when x is true? [i.e. the do nothing else clause]  My assert has measured slower, and I have not yet figured out why. (Ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit, c++v5)  I see you do not have the else clause that <cassert> (and my code) has.

Comment: A whole lot depends on what you do in `x` - if that is a function call to `find` on binary tree, and you then call `find` again, you've halved your function's performance. If on the other hand, `x` is a `bool` or `int` already returned from a function that you would use anyway, the overhead is small (but not zero). In some cases, the overhead comes from the compiler being able to optimize the code better when `assert` isn't used (reorder code more, vectorize a calculation, etc). An empty `else` is the same as no else for the compiler.

Comment: I think you are saying you have not.  Thanks anyway.  My next  'else clause' to test will be "static_cast<void>(0)'', previous was "static_cast<void>(expr )"

Comment: I haven't, but `static_cast<void>(expr)` should generate no code at all, since it's just a way to say `expr` is used to the compiler. It, under some conditions, avoids that you do `int x = something(); assert(x);` and compiler complaining that `x` is unused. When you say `else`, do you mean `#else` for the case where `NDEBUG` is configured? If so, this is the typical implementation, and very much the norm for standard assert. [Now, what this has to do with the original question is a bit debatable]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't output anything by itself, but allows us to see the string on inspection.
Basically, since a string is true as an expression, we can tag it on to any assertion and it will be there when the other part of the expression fails.

So in the case where assert prints to stderr, which many implementations do, the output will be something akin to `Assertion 'x > 0 && "Number must be above 0"'`, this will be the case in most circumstances on unix platforms.

In the case where NDEBUG is defined, it will simply be a no-op and preprocessed away.

Comment: In that case, what's the string useful for?
How would one go about using it?

Comment: It persists, and depending on the implementation it CAN be printed to stderr. For instance clang with libstd++ dumps the following message

`Assertion x > 0 && "Number must be above 0"' failed. Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: In a unix environment you are likely to see it printed from stderr with debug builds, note that if NDEBUG is defined assert will be defined as a no op.

Comment: I've not seen an assert that fired without reporting a file and line number.  With the file and line number, you can inspect the file and read the string.  If you do not believe the string or it is an insufficient explanation, you can next set a break point on the line, run to the breakpoint on the assert. and inspect the local variables for the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Assert messages are used when you are sure that a variable in your program will always have some defined value/range of values and if it takes any other value, it should indicate an error in your code which will make your program crash and it will print the assert message.

In your case, when I run your code, I get:

```
a.out: del.c:7: main: Assertion `x > 0 && "Number must be above 0"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Then I must be doing something wrong. When I run the above code exactly, my program exists (as it should), but i see no sort of error message (like the one you specified).

Comment: @CristianC.: I ran your code, and I see the assert message (see my updated ans)

Comment: In that case, this is very odd. I don't see the message. I'll google the problem a while, and see if I come up with any definitive answer as to why.